# how to blur the image in selected area in android?

Tags: android

Hi.
I am trying to implement a feature in the app that blurs some part of an image based on users (selection/touch) the selected area. I have implemented the code for whole image. But I am unable to find any example for the specified area of an image. So, please help me which type of example will use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it by the below link:
http://trickyandroid.com/advanced-blurring-techniques/

Now i am going to develop this link to drag and drop the selected blur area. But i am not getting to drop this blur in other area. please help for this.

Comment: link not working

Answer (score 1):

Just search before posting here :

Use this to blur your photo :

https://futurestud.io/blog/how-to-blur-images-efficiently-with-androids-renderscript

And use this to select the area you want

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/capture-and-crop-an-image-with-the-device-camera--mobile-11458

Comment: Can you give some reference for custom renderscript so everything is done efficiently at once on gpu?

Answer (score 0):

Use this to blur image sample example:
http://javatechig.com/android/how-to-create-bitmap-blur-effect-in-android-using-renderscript